# yarn link to a <relative-path>

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm using yarn to develop local lib for React. because you can't run 2 versions of React I'm usually doing `npm link ..\node_modules\react` in the test project to use the same react version as my linked package.

but I don't want to use npm, so I tried `yarn link ..\node_modules\react` which does not work, and also the [docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/) does not mention an option to do so.

I need to `cd ..\node_modules\react` and then `yarn link` then I could do `yarn link react` - but wants to avoid it, because who knows how many projects will need different versions of React.

so, there is a way to yarn link a directory that includes package.json file(`yarn link <relative-path>`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--why would there be two versions of React? If you're developing a library used by a React app, and the library uses React, wouldn't it be a `peerDependency`?

Comment: [see](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) and search`npm link`, `peerDependecy` is not enough to fix the version of react being used by the linked package and the example using the developed packaged (which may be using other react version)

Comment: But then you'd have the same problem in deployment, too; two versions of React.

Comment: no, in deploment i'm not using npm link at all

Comment: If your library has its own version of React it will conflict with the consumer's version.

Comment: it doesnt, is uses peerDependency, [see](https://github.com/Eliav2/react-xarrows/blob/master/package.json#L36)

Comment: ... I don't understand the problem then. What are you trying to link? The consuming app should link your library, and that should be sufficient.